# c# keep running application without run

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I was trying to implement key-logger and mouse-logger in .net. So I have a class `KeyLog` and `MouseLog`. Inside both class's constructor, I have this same logic :

MouseLog:

```
 public MouseLog()
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
            Application.Run();
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }
```

KeyLog :

```
public KeyLog()
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
            Application.Run();
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }
```

I'm using `Application.Run` to keep running the application.

**N.B.: It is a console application.**

Now I have another class, `PLog`(Parent Log), inside that I have :

```
public PLog()
{
      KeyLog();
      MouseLog();
}
```

This `PLog` is called from a `Main` method. The problem is If I put `KeyLog` before `MouseLog` in `PLog`, `MouseLog` doesn't work, else `KeyLog` doesn't work.

I can understand the problem, that it is not getting to the next statement, because `Application.Run` has already been called. **How can I resolve this?**

I don't want to use thread as this will keep running as long as the PC runs.

*using System.Windows.Forms;*

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove Application.Run from KeyLog and MouseLog and call it after setup hooks for both events
2. Consider to make unhook actions some events from application - like application closing or so.
3. It is better to use threads for such operations
4. If this is console application - why do you use Windows Forms to keep it running? May be it is better to use Thread.Sleep or something which is more suitable for this purpose.